# obj-c disable touches to cell after the first touch event

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6, cells

I have such a table that when a cell is touched, it makes updates but then is there a way to prevent that cell triggering the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` again?

I don't want to disable the table, just that cell.

My fall back is to remove the cell from the table but that isn't the ideal process for my workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep an array of indexPaths (if you want this to happen for multiple cells) for any cells you don't want to be selected, and return nil for the method, 
tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:, if the indexPath passed in is contained in your array. You would add the indexPaths to the array in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

The other way to disable touches entirely (the above method will show highlight when you touch down) would be to set userInteractionEnabled to NO in cellForRowAtIndexPath for any indexPath contained in your array, and to YES for all others.